# Determining a hyperbolic line from two points on Poincaré disk

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I tried to make a C++ program to make a hyperbolic line.

This is how I started:

I have two points, $P=(x_1, y_1)$ and $Q=(x_2, y_2)$, in the Poincaré disk. And the radius is 1.

$$\begin{align}
\alpha &= \frac{1}{x_1^2 + y_1^2} \qquad P^{-1} = (\alpha x_1, \alpha y_1) \\[4pt]
\beta &= \frac{1}{x_2^2 + y_2^2} \qquad Q^{-1} = (\beta x_2, \beta y_2)
\end{align}$$

Then calculate the center of the circle as the center of the two inverted points and the radius.

But the new circle does not intersect $P$ and $Q$.

What I doing wrong?

Comment: I took the liberty of changing some notation to be more mathematical. If you have strong objections, you may reverse those changes.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for my bad formatting.

Comment: The center of the target circle isn't "the center of the two inverted points". It's the center of the circle determined by (any three of) $P$, $Q$, $P^{-1}$, $Q^{-1}$. You can find this as the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of two pairs of those points; you can standardize this by taking the pair $P$ and $P^{-1}$ and the pair $Q$ and $Q^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's worked.

Comment: You should post your working solution as an answer, so that this question won't get auto-reposted in the future. (Plus, we can upvote your success.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on that site, I can make it.

http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Circle3D.htm